# How to redirect user when new node save by ajax in advance form block drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax

I have a website in drupal 7. I used advanced form block module to create add form block. Advanced form block module create block for form to edit and add new content. All node saved by ajax submission.

I want to redirect the user when new node save by this form. I used rules and form[#redirect] method in my hooks, but these are not working.

Can any one help me to figure out this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A form[#redirect] will not work in an AJAX form.

You can use an AJAX redirect command from CTools: [ctools_ajax_command_redirect](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!ajax.inc/function/ctools_ajax_command_redirect/7)

To do this, you should probably have to alter the form and use your own callback function returning the ajax command (along other needed data). I don't know advanced form block module so I can't say how difficult it is.

Example from http://dropbucket.org/node/1236:

```
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
  $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($path);
  print ajax_render($commands);
```

Comment: When I use this it will alert the whole page. I already tried this. I added exit in the last but it will redirect the page but not save the node in the database.

Comment: If you use exit you cut the execution flow and the submit handler is not executed, so node is not saved. I think your are not returning the AJAX command correctly.